# Query Function with Unique References

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function

I am currently using the `QUERY` function to move relative information to another sheet, which is then used for forecasting. Now what is currently happening is the same business names are showing up in the forecasting sheet. I have a correct `QUERY` function, to further this I would like to then remove duplicates from that function. How do I do this?

My current formula is:

```
=QUERY(Business!$A$2:$H$1000,"select A,C,D,G, H order by A desc limit 1000 ")
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try **`=UNIQUE`** ?

**`=UNIQUE(QUERY(Business!$A$2:$H$1000,"select A, C, D, G, H order by A desc limit 1000 "))`**